# When is std::reference_wrapper converted to T&?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-wrapper

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void fun(T t) 
{ 
    t+=8;
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    fun(ref(i));
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

This code prints "8". I assume that the t in fun() is automatically converted to an int&.

But if I replace `t+=8` with `t=8`, the program will not compile.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reference_wrapper<T>` has an implicit conversion operator to `T &`, so it will be converted to `T &` wherever a `T &` is a better match than a `reference_wrapper<T>`.

In the augmented assignment expression, the only viable operator is `int &operator+=(int &, int)` so the `int &` is extracted.

In the assignment expression, the member operator `reference_wrapper<int>::operator=(const reference_wrapper<int> &)` is also available, so the member operator is preferred; the compiler then attempts to construct a reference wrapper from the constant `8`, which fails.  The assignment operator has the effect of rebinding, which is necessary for facilities like `tie` to work as expected.

This means that reference wrappers are closer to references in languages like Python than C++ references:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 2;
    std::ref(i) = j;
    std::cout << i << '\n';                 // prints '1'
}
```